# ngModel on the same form field as formControlName. Support for using the ngModel input property and ngModelChange event with reactive form deprecated

Tags: angular

So does it mean that we are not going enjoy the glamour of two way binding?

For ex: In NG6 I have a customer list(custList) which creates a reactive form and the ngModel is being used for 2-way data binding. When change a property from UI for a specific customer, it reflects in custList too. Angular code for NG6 as follows;

In My Component;

```
let custForm: FormGroup;
let custFormArray = new Array();

custList.forEach(cust => {
 custFormArray.push(new FormGroup({
    id: new FormControl(cust .id),
    name: new FormControl(cust.name, [Validators.required])
  }));
});

this.custForm = this.fb.group({
  custFormArray: this.fb.array(custFormArray)
});
```

In my template;

```
<div *ngIf="custList?.length > 0" [formGroup]="custForm">
  <div formArrayName="custFormArray">
    <div *ngFor="let cust of custList; let i=index">
      <div [formGroupName]="i">
       <input formControlName="id" [(ngModel)]="cust.id">
       <input formControlName="name" [(ngModel)]="cust.name">
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

New Way:(No ngModel binding)

```
<div *ngIf="custList?.length > 0" [formGroup]="custForm">
 <div formArrayName="custFormArray">
  <div *ngFor="let cust of custList; let i=index">
    <div [formGroupName]="i">
       <input formControlName="id">
       <input formControlName="name">
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

When I use the above way, a change from the UI doesn't propagate the custList which breaks the two way data binding model. Only way I can access the changes via the following;

```
let customerList =Object.assign({}, this.custForm.value.custFormArray) as   Array;

let specificCustomer = customerList[specificCustomerIndex];
```

where custForm is the formName and custFormArray is the form array.

Means that I need to do the same thing wherever I want to access the modified list.

Can anybody answer me whether this is intentional in the new version?

Comment: The 2 way databinding is still working but you have to chose between reactve forms (formGroups, formArrays and formControls) and template-driven forms ( [(ngModel)] ).
If I am looking your code fine, the [formGroupName]="i" part of the code is what makes the mess there, try removing it and the 2 way databinding should works if I am getting your code ok

Comment: Well, I have multiple customers in the custList and need to display a block for each customer. The unique reference to each customer is the "i". Measn that I cant remove the indexer.

Comment: If I am not wrong you should choose between using [(ngModel)] or formControlName, it is not recomended to use both kind of forms in the same form (reactive form https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) (and template form https://angular.io/guide/forms#introduction-to-template-driven-forms)